# Can't send_Keys to selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
driver= webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://www.dsvv.ac.in/")

search= driver.find_elements_by_id('site-search')

search.send_Keys('meditation')
```

`'list' object has no attribute 'send_Keys'  error shows when try to find element by find_elements_by_id('site-search')`.

```
'WebElement' object has no attribute 'send_Keys'  error shows when try to find element by find_element_by_id('site-search').
```

Error shows when try to send keys only,otherwise it works fine.
Can anyone help me for this?

Comment: Should be `send_keys` not `send_Keys` (notice the case difference in `k`)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem lies here:

```
search= driver.find_elements_by_id('site-search')
```

find_elements_by_id will return a list and not an element. Either use

```
search= driver.find_element_by_id('site-search')
```

(note the missing s) or

```
search[0].send_keys('meditation')
```

Comment: I have written in the question error shows when try to search search= driver.find_element_by_id('site-search'). 
And indexing also not works for me.
And it works find when the just only find element id not send keys.
So Error only shows when send_keys only.

Comment: Check your spelling. As pointed out above, it is send_keys and not send_Keys.